# Simplest way to display custom message on stdout upon install of my conda package

Tags: python, conda, packaging, conda-build

**The scenario:**

- We maintain some conda packages that are used internally in the company
- For some of these packages we have little knowledge of where and how the packages are used (the users download and install the packages on their local python installations)
- To better support the users and projects that consume the packages, we would like to know more about the usages of these packages.

**I would like to display a message on stdout when the user installs a package:**

`Please let us know that you're using the xxx package: send an e-mail to ...@example.com, notify us on the teams channel, or update the wiki page ... directly. Thanks!`

**Question:**

- What would be the easiest way to make `conda install` display a custom message upon successful package installation? Preferably something that works on both Linux and Windows.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This can be done with a [`post-link` script in your recipe.](https://docs.conda.io/projects/conda-build/en/latest/resources/link-scripts.html)  As noted in the documentation, you must write your message to `${PREFIX}/.messages.txt`, not `stdout` or `stderr`.

Example recipe:

```
foobar-recipe/
├── meta.yaml
├── post-link.bat
└── post-link.sh
```

```yaml
# meta.yaml
package:
  name: foobar
  version: 0.1
```

```sh
#!/bin/bash

# post-link.sh

cat << EOF >> ${PREFIX}/.messages.txt


*****************************
Thanks for installing foobar!
*****************************
EOF
```

(For Windows, implement `post-link.bat`.)

Build it:

```sh
$ conda build foobar-recipe
```

Test Install:

```
$ conda create -y -n test-foobar --use-local foobar
Collecting package metadata (current_repodata.json): done
Solving environment: done

## Package Plan ##

  environment location: /opt/miniconda/envs/test-foobar

  added / updated specs:
    - foobar


The following NEW packages will be INSTALLED:

  foobar             opt/miniconda/conda-bld/osx-64::foobar-0.1-0


Preparing transaction: done
Verifying transaction: done
Executing transaction: /

*****************************
Thanks for installing foobar!
*****************************

done
#
# To activate this environment, use
#
#     $ conda activate test-foobar
#
# To deactivate an active environment, use
#
#     $ conda deactivate
```